# SPARQL: How to get a list of owl:onProperty on a selected class

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl

how can i get a list of all the properties for a selected class?  Example:

```xml
<!-- http://www.xxx.xx/ontologies/abcd.owl#selected -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="&selected;Selected">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&selected;a_xxyy"/>
            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&selected;aaaaa"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&selected;a_yyzz"/>
            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&selected;bbbb"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&selected;a_gggrrr"/>
            <owl:allValuesFrom>
                <rdfs:Datatype>
                    <owl:onDatatype rdf:resource="&xsd;integer"/>
                    <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType="Collection">
                        <rdf:Description>
                            <xsd:minInclusive rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">18</xsd:minInclusive>
                        </rdf:Description>
                    </owl:withRestrictions>
                </rdfs:Datatype>
            </owl:allValuesFrom>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
```

I wanna all the properties (and even the value) for the class `<http://www.xxx.xx/ontologies/abcd.owl#selected>`, like

```
|property|value|
|a_xxyy  |aaaaa|
|a_yyzz  |bbbb |
|a_gggrrr|<18  |
```

Comment: Please be sure to *proofread* your question after posting, or even better, check the preview before posting.  I've just realized that the raw text of your question contained some information that the rendered version didn't.  I've made [some updates](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25872934/revisions), but you should check them for correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all the properties for a selected class

The RDF serialization you're showing is a bunch of equivalent class axioms where one of the classes is an anonymous restriction class.  E.g.,

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:about="&selected;Selected">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&selected;a_xxyy"/>
            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&selected;aaaaa"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
```

says that

> Selected ≡ ∀a_xxyy.aaaaa

which means that every value an instance of **Selected** has for the property **a_xxyy** must be an **aaaaa**.  That doesn't really mean that **a_xxyy** is "a property for the class", though.  After, a similarly structured axiom is

> Human ⊑ ∀hasExoskeleton.Nothing

which says that no human has an exoskeleton.  Thus **hasExoskeleton** wouldn't be considered  "a property for Human". The *form* of the axiom is the same, though.

At any rate, the SPARQL query isn't very complicated.  It would just be:

```sql
prefix owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

select ?class ?property where {
  ?class owl:equivalentClass/owl:onProperty ?property
}
```

In reality, you'd probably want not just owl:equivalentClasses, but rdfs:subClasses too, so you could do:

```sql
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

select ?class ?property where {
  ?class (rdfs:subClassOf|owl:equivalentClass)/owl:onProperty ?property
}
```

Comment: First a great "thank you" for the quick answer! After... in the ontology i wanna say that if something is an istance of Selected this "something" has to have that the property "a_xxyy" values "aaaaa". Is this correct for you? ok... in any case i want to specify the name of the class in the query, because i wanna only the properties of "Selected" and not all the propertis of each classes. Sorry if i havn't speak clearly befaore on this! tnx!

Comment: @MaxCalzone My point is that just because something is an "owl:allValuesFrom" restriction *doesn't* mean that an equivalent class or subclass necessarily has some value for the associated property.  I can say that "all my brothers are lawyers", and it's true, because I don't have any brothers.  I can also say that "all my employees are square circles", and that's true because I don't have any employees.  However, it *also* enforces that I can never have any employees, because there can't be any square circles.  The kind of axiom you're using doesn't carry the intent that you're describing.

Comment: ok... i think to understand what u say so ... I can fix these putting all in a unique big restriction where "all my brothers are lawyers" AND "they are alive" AND "they are males" AND "they are sons of my father OR thery are sons of my mother"... the point for me really important now is to (first learn better owl and sparql for sure :)  identify all the properties for one selected class... so i think i have to specify in the query the "name" of the class... but i don't know how! tnx however

Comment: @MaxCalzone You just write `<http://www.xxx.xx/ontologies/abcd.owl#selected>` instead of `?class` in the `where` part, and do `select ?property where {` instead of `select ?class ?property where {`.  Is that what you're asking?